# Can't extract float value by JsonPath: $.metrics.covered_percent in github-pr-coverage-status-plugin

Tags: github, jenkins-plugins, code-coverage

I am facing below issue in publishing code coverage report to github using 
"github-pr-coverage-status-plugin"

ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Strange SimpleCov report!
Can't extract float value by JsonPath: $.metrics.covered_percent
from:
{"/Users/iradchenko/sandbox/cli-width/index.js":{"path":"/Users/iradchenko/sandbox/cli-width/index.js","s":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":6,"5":1,"6":5,"7":5,"8":1,"9":4,"10":2,"11":2,"12":1,"13":3},"b":{"1":[1,5],"2":[1,4],"3":[2,2],"4":[1,1]},"f":{"1":6},"fnMap":{"1":{"name":"cliWidth","line":6,"loc":{"start":{"line":6,"column":0},"end":{"line":6,"column":20}}}},"statementMap":{"1":{"start":{"line":3,"column":0},"end":{"line":3,"column":36}},"2":{"start":{"line":4,"column":0},"end": ......

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

By default github-pr-coverage-status-plugin is trying to find all supportable coverage reports one of them is SimpleCov. There are a lot of files which are similar to that but wrong. As result plugin fails with that error.

If you need to support SimpleCov format just add step before plugin to remove redundant. 
Otherwise you can disable SimpleCov coverage and use only Jacoco, Cobertura as described here https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-pr-coverage-status-plugin/releases/tag/github-pr-coverage-status-1.9.1

Comment: Terma, could you please add to that plugin the fact that it searches for project by key and not by name ? or both ! Thanks, and good plugin, Also may be in later time, compare coverage would be good if it was we could choose the branch to which to compare

Comment: In fact, you can select branch, plugins relays on coverage recorder which collects static from your build, so you can just specify what branch you want to build.